# Загрузить данные из XML файла как массив

Tags: функции, kotlin

Как вынуть  массив из файла на KOTLIN? У меня есть файл `xml`.
Получаю имя файла:

```
val nameFile = File (pathname:"thismyFile.xml")
```

В этом файле у меня массив, но как его достать?
Есть ли функция `arrayOfFile`? Если нет, то как вызвать?
В документации смотрела, не нашла. Может, не там ищу.

Comment: Если совсем кратко: парсить XML

Comment: В файле же не массив, а байты. Вы просто представили, что там массив. Здесь примеры кода должны подойти https://turreta.com/2017/07/07/how-to-read-xml-in-kotlin-using-dom-parser/. Ну это как я бы искал, по Kotlin не специалист. На будущее: функций, которых нет в документации - нет. А если есть, то лучше на них не надеяться.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию. Но  у меня файлик xml попроще чем в примере. Надеюсь , что без Парсинга обойтись можно.

Comment: Прикрепите xml файл покажите ваши попытки. Вас быстро напраят в нужное русло

Comment: Массив в XML файле может быть представлен десятком разных способов, поэтому не может существовать какой-то универсальной функции `arrayOfFile`. Добавьте в вопрос конкретный пример массива в XML файле.

Comment: У вас проблема прочесть файл, или разобрать его? XML это текстовый формат, читайте его как текст и разбирайте, хотите парсером, хотите вручную.